# Tengo un problema para hacer una autentificación en Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-auth

Tengo un problema para hacer una autentificación en Firebase. Y creo que el problema está en la url del servicio. Si voy a mi cuenta de Firebase y me voy a la documentación en el apartado de "Authentication and user management" y vamos al apartado de "Sign in with email / password" me indica esta url:

- "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]"

La anterior URL me da un error, pero si por el contrario uso esta otra url (que la he visto en un curso de internet, pero no la veo en la documentación de Firebase por ninguna parte) todo me funciona correctamente:

- "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API_KEY]"

Aqué se debe esto?

---

Vale, la URL "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]" si que me funciona. El problema es que no concatenaba bieen el string en el código:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UsuarioModel } from '../models/usuario.model';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  //private url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty';

  private url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:';
  
  

  //private apikey = 'AIzaSyCr--fzsw8mVaADP3mPVyy72vsQKvJ6cYY';

  //https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]


  //private url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1';
  private apikey = 'AIzaSyBRyoUmuUs6K9Kjja3siXE17N6m3GrdUpA';



  userToken: string;

  // Crear nuevo usuario
  // https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API_KEY]


  // Login
  // https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]


  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
    this.leerToken();
  }


  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  login( usuario: UsuarioModel ) {

    const authData = {
      ...usuario,
      returnSecureToken: true
    };

    console.log("llamamos al login");
    console.log(usuario);

    return this.http.post(
      //`${ this.url }/accounts:signUp?key=${ this.apikey }`,
      `${ this.url }signInWithPassword?key=${ this.apikey }`,
      authData
    ).pipe(
      map( resp => {
        this.guardarToken( resp['idToken'] );
        return resp;
      })
    );

  }

  nuevoUsuario( usuario: UsuarioModel ) {

    const authData = {
      ...usuario,
      returnSecureToken: true
    };

    return this.http.post(
      `${ this.url }signUp?key=${ this.apikey }`,
      authData
    ).pipe(
      map( resp => {
        this.guardarToken( resp['idToken'] );
        return resp;
      })
    );

  }


  private guardarToken( idToken: string ) {

    this.userToken = idToken;
    localStorage.setItem('token', idToken);

    let hoy = new Date();
    hoy.setSeconds( 3600 );

    localStorage.setItem('expira', hoy.getTime().toString() );


  }

  leerToken() {

    if ( localStorage.getItem('token') ) {
      this.userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    } else {
      this.userToken = '';
    }

    return this.userToken;

  }


  estaAutenticado(): boolean {

    if ( this.userToken.length < 2 ) {
      return false;
    }

    const expira = Number(localStorage.getItem('expira'));
    const expiraDate = new Date();
    expiraDate.setTime(expira);

    if ( expiraDate > new Date() ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }


  }


}
```

Mi pregunta es, la URL "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]" va a dejar de ser válida?

Answer (score 2):

Al ver que usas la versión 1 de *Identity Toolkit* y es la que presenta el problema:

> `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]`

te puedo comentar que esta estará obsoleta. De hecho, revisando la documentación, específicamente el 30 de junio dejará de funcionar por completo. Te sugiero no usarla y ahora usar el SDK de *Firebase*.

> *On June 30, 2020, the SDKs documented on this page and the API setting page will stop functioning. (The https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/... and https://securetoken.googleapis.com/... endpoints, used by Identity Platform and Firebase Authentication, will continue to function.)*

---

Revisa el documento de migración, esta vez se realizará mediante Firebase, debes [agregar el SDK de Firebase a tu proyecto](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase#android) y agregar la *library* [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth) :

- https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase
- https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase#android

Comment: Ok, gracias. Soy novato con todo esto y lo del SDK me parece un lío de momento (no entiendo muy bien los conceptos todavía). Respecto a la segunda URL que si me funciona ("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API_KEY]") seguirá activa? hay alguna documentación al respeto de esa URL para dar de alta, login, etc...